# How to simplify functions in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a for loop containing the following:

```
for (i in 1:100) {

  #calculate correlation
  correlationList1a[[i]] <- sapply(seq(1,14), 
                    function(x) cor(validationSetsA.list[[i]][,x], medianListA[[i]]))
  correlationList2a[[i]] <- sapply(seq(1,14), 
                    function(x) cor(validationSetsA.list[[i]][,x], medianListB[[i]]))

}
```

How can I simplify this?  `correlationList1a` and `correlationList2a` are basically doing the same thing the only thing that is different is that correlation1a contains `medianListA` and `correlationList2a` contains `medianListB`.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal, self contained example**. Check these links for general ideas, and how to do it in R: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [**here**](http://www.sscce.org/), [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html), and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: Sounds like a job for `mapply` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a case for `mapply`.

```
mapply(function(x, y) apply(x[,seq(1,14)], 2, cor, y=y), 
       x = validationSetsA.list, 
       y = medianListA, 
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```